# How to scale Node.js application in standard way locally and between servers (cluster API is still experimental)?

Tags: multithreading, node.js, cluster-computing, scalability, web-farm

**How to scale Node.js application in standard way locally and between servers?**

[Cluster API](http://www.nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) as of Node v0.10.18 is still experimental, that is API is very like to change that is risk for big project.

Are there other standard practices, tools to scale automatically (raise up number of running instances on the same server and on other servers)

This question is not about making inter-process communication like [Node.js multi-server cluster: how to share object in several nodes cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956913/node-js-multi-server-cluster-how-to-share-object-in-several-nodes-cluster) or [How to make a node.js server with rooms scalable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070853/how-to-make-a-node-js-server-with-rooms-scalable), but **what infrastructure could automatically manage number of Node.js instances?**

How to automatically start Node.js apps on other server? Are there ready-to-use tools or framework to automate "deploying" Node.js apps?

Setting up [load balancers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15425647/how-to-make-a-distributed-node-js-application), [security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473284/what-are-the-basics-of-securely-interconnecting-node-js-applications-workers-clu) would be next steps.

Comment: What is your programming question? Infrastructure questions aren't good fits for StackOverflow.

Comment: How to automate "deploying": that is get Node.js app code on other server (e.g. when update is needed), start and stop it. Are there Node.js supervisors to do that?

Comment: Find a "tool" or library questions also aren't a good fit.